# Why non-trampolined IO monad implementation from FP in Scala book yields StackOverflowError?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm going through the Functional Programming in Scala book. In the chapter 13. External effects and I/O, point 13.3 Avoiding the StackOverflowError, page 237 there is an example of how a simple program with the IO monad developed through the chapter can provoke a `StackOverflowError`.

The crashing code is simple:

```
IO.forever(IO { println("Still going...") }).run
```

The source for the IO trait and companion object can be found [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/7a43335a04679e140c8c4cf7c359fd8a39bbe39f/exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/iomonad/IO.scala#L61)

I couldn't see at first glance why the `StackOverflowError` is thrown, so I worked through the example, expanding and evaluating expressions, as if I were the Scala runtime. After some iterations, I'm returning to the point of departure (`t.run`). I cannot reach the situation where multiple calls to `run` are being piled on the call stack:

```
IO.forever(IO { println("Still going...") }).run
t.run
(a.flatMap(_ => t)).run
(new IO[Unit] {
  def run = (_ => t)(self.run).run
}).run
(_ => t)(self.run).run
  > "Still going..."
(_ => t)(()).run
t.run
```

The definition of `forever` is straightforward:

```
def forever[A,B](a: F[A]): F[B] = {
  lazy val t: F[B] = a.flatMap(_ => t)
  t
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my *pencil and paper* evaluation? Is Scala evaluating the `lazy val` `t` earlier that *my-brain-Scala*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a problem with the `lazy val`. Rather, you just implicitly applied tail call optimisation when going from

```
(new IO[Unit] {
  def run = (_ => t)(self.run).run
}).run
```

to

```
(_ => t)(self.run).run
```

while actually it is calling the `self.run` while still in the context of the outer `run` evaluation - it has not yet returned from the `def run`.

Comment: You mean that:

`(new IO[Unit] {  def run = (_ => t)(self.run).run }).run`

gets evaluated to:

`> "Still going..." /* from self.run */   (new IO[Unit] {  def run = t.run }).run`
? Is `new IO[Unit] {  def run = ... }` evaluated on the construction of the anonymous IO trait instance?

Comment: Yes. No. I dunno, this term rewriting doesn't seem to be suited well to represent the call stack anywhere

Comment: According to [Scala Language Reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#method-types), section *3.3.1. Method Types*: "A special case are types of methods without any parameters. They are written here => T. Parameterless methods name expressions that are re-evaluated each time the parameterless method name is referenced.". If I get it right, a *parameterless method* (`new IO[Unit] { def run = ... }` in this case) is evaluated on the first reference, i.e. in the outer run.

Comment: Yes. First it constructs the `IO[Unit]` instance, then it calls the parameterless `run` method on it. And *during the evaluation of the `run` body* (i.e. with `run` still on the stack), it will call `self.run` and then `t.run`

Comment: Makes sense. I was evaluating expression as if it were Haskell and I forgot that JVM is stack-based. I found a good excerpt from Alvin Alexander's "Functional Programming, Simplified" - [JVM Stacks and Stack Frames](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/recursion-jvm-stacks-stack-frames) that explains the implications of JVM call stack for Scala functions.